# Microsoft Graph find meeting time targetSmtpAddress error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query Microsoft Graph beta branch for me/findMeetingTimes, but all I can get is error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "The value is set to null\r\nParameter name: targetSmtpAddress",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "eb163718-457d-4715-af4d-59f934fffaa7",
            "date": "2017-07-19T08:53:32"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same result running the query from Graph Explorer. There is no targetSmtpAddress parameter I could find.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if calendar is enabled on this account?

Comment: (facepalm)... of course... i was using dev account without access to mail or calendar. Thanks :)